# What are the exact parameters of Apple's Defocus filter?

Tags: transparency, sketch-app, photoshop-effects, blur, apple

Apple OS X does a fine job of [blurring images](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH16322?locale=en_US&viewlocale=en_US) with gaussian blur and opacity.

[image]

Does anyone have the parameters for using PhotoshoSketch to achieve this precision?

Apple defocus[image: defocus]
My defocus [image: guaissian w/sketch 80% not cropped]

Comment: Have you tried anything? Can you open Photoshop or Sketch and try some settings? Seems simple enough to just try it yourself and quickly find out.

Comment: I came close, but not perfect.

Comment: Can you add your sample here so we can help you move forward? Otherwise your question might be closed since A: we don't know where you're stuck and B: there's not enough details to help. Show us what is the difference between your sample and Apple's, from memory it just looks the same to me.